# Result of complex exponential fourier series approximation and trignometric fourier series approximation are not exactly same in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, frequency-spectrum, frequency, fourier, fourier-series

I have a signal and i am trying to observe its approximations using complex exponential fourier series and trignometric fourier series but i am not getting exactly same result(graph of trignometirc fourier series approximation has more  ripples compared to graph of complex exponential fourier series approximation)

Despite the fact exactly same signal is used for both complex exponential fourier series and trignometric foureir series and approximation is made for 11 terms in both cases

**My MATLAB code for  complex exponential fourier series**

```
clc;clear;close all
syms t
t0= 0;
T=2;
w=2*pi/T;
x=heaviside(t)-heaviside(t-1);
ezplot(x,[0 2])
legend('x(t)')

%computing coefficients
figure
k=-5:5;
a=(1/T)*int(x*exp(-j*k*w*t), t,t0,t0+T);
xx=sum(a.*exp(j*k*w*t));
ezplot(xx,[0 2])
legend('Approximation with 11 terms')
```

Its output graph
[image]

**My MATLAB code for trignometric fourier series**

```
clc;clear;close all
syms t
x=(heaviside(t)-heaviside(t-1)); 
t0=0;
T=2;
w=2*pi/T;
ezplot(x,[0 2])
legend('x(t)')


% computing coefficients
n=1:10;
b=(2/T)*int(x*cos(n*w*t),t,t0,t0+T); 
c=(2/T)*int(x*sin(n*w*t),t,t0,t0+T);
a0=(1/T)*int(x,t0,t0+T);
%approximation
figure
xx=a0+sum(b.*cos(n*w*t))+sum(c.*sin(n*w*t));
ezplot(xx,[0 2])
legend('Approximation with 11 terms')
```

Its output graph
[image]

Comment: what does `ezplot` plot *actually* here when you feed in complex numbers?

Comment: With `k=-5:5` the highest frequency you have is `k=5`. With `n=1:10` it is `n=10`. Of course in the latter case you see twice as high frequencies in the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each sinusoid is a pair of exponentials. And the DC term is one term in both cases. We see this from the relationship between sinusoidal frequencies and exponential frequencies as given by Euler's formula.

For cosine this is related as:

$$2\cos(\omega t) = e^{j\omega t} + e^{-j\omega t}$$

And for sine this is related as:

$$2\sin(\omega t) = -j e^{j\omega t} + j e^{-j\omega t}$$

Thus the DC + 10 cosine terms that the OP uses for the trigonometric series would require DC + 20 exponential terms (indexed from -10 to 10) for implementing with the exponential Fourier Series.

Comment: "Thus the DC + 11 cosine terms that the OP uses for the trigonometric series would require DC + 22 exponential terms (indexed from -11 to 11) for implementing with the exponential Fourier Series."  

please check again , according to my understanding, there are DC+ 10  that the OP uses for the trigonometric series

Comment: @Engr yes! Thanks, I am getting too used to Python indexing